# Ruby Koans and Strings

Tags: ruby, string

I'm trying to understand something from the Ruby Koans.  In one lesson, we make two classes as follows:

```
class CanNotBeTreatedAsString
  def to_s
    "non-string-like"
  end
end

not_like_a_string = CanNotBeTreatedAsString.new
not_like_a_string == "non-string-like"

class CanBeTreatedAsString
  def to_s
    "string-like"
  end

  def to_str
    to_s
  end
end

like_a_string = CanBeTreatedAsString.new
like_a_string.to_str == "string-like"

def acts_like_a_string?(string)
  string = string.to_str if string.respond_to?(:to_str)
  string.is_a?(String)
end

assert_equal false, acts_like_a_string?(CanNotBeTreatedAsString.new)
assert_equal true,  acts_like_a_string?(CanBeTreatedAsString.new)
```

So the two classes and last two "assert" statements are what I'm not clear about.  The two classes are nearly identical, except for the fact that the second class simply has another function `to_str` that makes a call to `to_s`.  I don't see why the second assert statement is true (and thus the second class can be treated as a string) simply because there's a second function making a call to the first function.

Answer (score 3):

There's no magic here. The second test is checking for the presence of  `to_str` method. This  is not defined for `CanNotBeTreatedAsString` but it *is* defined for `CanBeTreatedAsString`.

The function of `respond_to?` is to test if a method is defined, and in Ruby 2.0 it will further indicate if it can be called. Protected methods, which cannot be called, will no longer count. For now if `respond_to?(:method_name)` returns `true` then `send(:method_name)` with any required arguments would theoretically work.

The second class could use `alias :to_str, :to_s` to achieve the same result with less code.

Comment: I noticed the key to the problem I had is the way `acts_like_a_string?` is defined.  I changed the code slightly in irb so it responds to `:to_s` instead.

Answer (score 3):

The point of this lesson is to illustrate the principle known as '[duck-typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).'  Basically, if it looks like a duck and quacks like a duck, then it is a duck.  In this case, the only factor that determines if something is a string (or rather acts like a string) is if it responds to the `to_str` method.

Try running this code in an interactive ruby (`irb`) session and experimenting with the two classes.  You will find that an instance of each class will respond to `to_s` but only `CanBeTreatedAsString` will respond to `to_str`.  That means that, as far as Ruby is concerned, `CanBeTreatedAsString` is as much of a String as anything else that responds to `to_str`.